# jQuery works on jsFiddle but not on localhost

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-animate

I don't understand what happened. The last code I created works fine in console of jsFiddle but doesn't work in Firefox when I test it on localhost.

Here's some example code: it doesn't work on localhost while it works on jsFiddle and I see the code and I don't see anything bad.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<style>
#boton
{
width:200px;
height:30px;
border:1px solid;
background-color:#cccccc;
}

.botonclass
{
width:250px;
height:300px;
border:1px solid;
background-color:#FF0000;
}
</style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#boton").mouseover(function(){
$(this).addClass("botonclass",1000);
});

});
</script>

</head>



<body>


<div id="boton">Hello</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Could somebody test this on their computer and tell me if you get the same result (the code not working on localhost)? Thanks, regards

Edit: The code that should run is this: `$(this).addClass("botonclass",1000);` -- I added an alert in the original provided code to check whether or not the mouseover handler was running, but it's this line specifically that seems to not run.

Comment: What does no work mean? no alert? no class animation? are you getting a js error?

Comment: It works in Chrome, hovering over the "hello" box  gives an alert (ok).

Comment: P.D : The Effec that must load it´s : $(this).addClass("botonclass",1000);
 , no alert , alert i put for know if works fine mouseover , thank´s

Comment: I'm sorry, but since English is not my first language, I really have no clue of what your 'edit' means.

Comment: Which language use .....

Comment: I tried improving your English to make it more understandable. Just edit/roll back the changes if you don't agree

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean with localhost? Do you have Apache running or are you just saving this as a HTML-file and are you opening this with Firefox?

Perhaps it helps if the libraries are locally stored, and not downloaded from Google Api or jQuery.com. Perhaps your firewall is blocking external requests from locally stored files. Running a local server (XAMPP of WAMPserver e.g.)  will fix this problem.

Comment: P.D : The Effec that must load it´s : $(this).addClass("botonclass",1000);
 , no alert , alert i put for know if works fine mouseover , thank´s

Comment: My thoughts exactly - I think it's being run as a local file, rather than in a web server.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me, after hover on the box I've got an alert.

Download all JavaScripts to the disk and use it instead of remote locations to check if it helps you.

Comment: P.D : The Effec that must load it´s : $(this).addClass("botonclass",1000);
 , no alert , alert i put for know if works fine mouseover , thank´s